# Storm statictics for any window

Tags: apache-storm

How can I get statistics for any window in Apache Storm? By default Storm has statictics for 600, 10800, 86400 seconds. I want to know information about last 5 minutes, for example.

Comment: Need more information. Do you mean topology statistics?

Comment: @PWhite, yes, I can choose in Storm UI topology stats between 10m, 3h, 1d, but I need different duration

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Storm API Documentation](http://storm.apache.org/releases/0.9.6/STORM-UI-REST-API.html) one of the parameters of the `/api/v1/topology/:id` endpoint is `window`, which is "Window duration for metrics in seconds."

Comment: It returns wrong statictics for any window parameter value except 600, 10800 and 86400.

Comment: Ah, I see. It appears that Storm stores statistics in predefined buckets - i.e. 10 minutes, 3 hours, 1 day, and all time - likely with decreasing precision - and they get demoted to the next bucket once they're old enough.